# Functions from $\{w,x,y,z\}$ to $\{a,b,c\}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I'm having some problems understanding how functions and Big-O notation works... I've checked a couple of other threads here but still unsure

Let's say I have $A = \{w, x, y, z\}$ and $B = \{a, b, c\}$.

- What are all the functions $f: A \to B$?
- How many are one-to-one from $f: A \to B$? From $g: B \to A$?
- What about functions $f: A \to B$ that satisfy $f(w) = a$? Wouldn't this be just 1 function since one of the functions is $(w, a)$?

Comment: Please ask only one question per posting. Also take a look at [the notation help page](/help/notation) to see how to format Math at this site.

Comment: ah my apologies. i'll remove the big O notation one.

Comment: No problem. I've edited your post to make it more readable. You may want to look at the new markup to see how to properly format your questions.

Comment: reading it now, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with telling you how to write down such a function $f: A \to B$. $(w,a)$ is *not* a proper way to do this. Instead you must specify the image of every element of $A$, i.e. $f(w), f(x), f(y)$ and $f(z)$. Each of these must be an element of $B$ and we can make our notation more compact by identifying the function $f$ with the vector $(f(w), f(x), f(y), f(z)) \in B \times B \times B \times B = B^4$ ($\times$ denotes the carthesian product).

1. This now asks how many vectors are there in $B^4$? Well, we have four choices to make and three elements to chose from each time. That's a total of $3^4 = 81$.
2. One-to-one (a.k.a. injective) functions don't map to the same element more than once. This is impossible for we'd have to chose four distinct elements from $B$ to map to, but there are only three. This means there are $0$ injective functions from $A$ to $B$.
   For the other way around, we must:

   - Chose three elements from $A$ to map to
   - Arrange these three elements as images of $a,b$ and $c$

   This boils down to $\binom43 \cdot 3! = 4\cdot 6 = 24$ injective functions from $B$ to $A$
3. Now we ask how many elements are there in $\{(f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4) \mid f_1 = a; f_2,f_3,f_4\in B \}$.
   You should be able to figure out that this boils down to chosing three times out of three, i.e. $3^3 = 27$ functions $f: A \to B$ with $f(w) = a$.

Comment: ah makes sense now. thanks alex! For the one-to-one, since A has 4 values and B has 3, can we not map 3 of A to 3 of B? I guess we can't choose 3 from A and map them to 3 from B?

Comment: @matthew The problem is you must map all elements of the LHS, so you can't leave one element unmapped.

Comment: that's what I figured... thanks alex